# getting error on grub installation

Tags: 10.10, grub2

I get this error when I run `grub-install`:

```
cp: cannot stat `/usr/local/lib/grub/i386-pc/*.mod': No such file or directory
```

I thought I'd run grub-mkconfig for a fresh configuration file that grub-install could then use, but it still didn't help. Then I did some stupid things like deleting files in /boot/grub and reinstalling grub packages in hopes to restore them, to no avail. Why does this error come up, and what can I do to reinstall a completely fresh grub system, including any files related to grub.

Thanks.

Comment: After some investigation, I found that the directory `/usr/local/lib/grub` doesn't come standard in Ubuntu (and probably linux in general). This folder exists because I compiled the grub source. Not sure why reinstalling grub didn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall grub2:

> sudo apt-get purge grub grub-pc
>   grub-common
>
> sudo apt-get install grub-common
>   grub-pc
>
> sudo update-grub

Comment: this will also purge grub legacy (you probably don't and shouldn't have it installed)

Comment: Now I get << The following Linux command line was extracted from /etc/default/grub or the `kopt' parameter in GRUB Legacy's menu.lst.  Please verify that it is correct, and modify it if necessary.>> and an empty Linux command line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tryed Grub-Customizer? Maybe you'll like it:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer && sudo apt-get update

Then, install it:

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer.

You can controll all of your boot system from here with safety and less headache.